# How to respond to a command line promt with node.js

Tags: node.js, express, stdout, stdin, command-line-interface

How would I respond to a command line prompt programmatically with node.js? For example, if I do `process.stdin.write('sudo ls');` The command line will prompt for a password. Is there an event for 'prompt?'

Also, how do I know when something like `process.stdin.write('npm install')` is complete?

I'd like to use this to make file edits (needed to stage my app), deploy to my server, and reverse those file edits (needed for eventually deploying to production).

Any help would rock!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to use [`child_process.exec()`](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback) to do this rather than writing the command to `stdin`.

```
var sys = require('sys'),
    exec = require('child_process').exec;

// execute the 'sudo ls' command with a callback function
exec('sudo ls', function(error, stdout, stderr){
  if (!error) {
    // print the output
    sys.puts(stdout);
  } else {
    // handle error
  }
});
```

For the `npm install` one you might be better off with [`child_process.spawn()`](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options) which will let you attach an event listener to run when the process exits. You could do the following:

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

// run 'npm' command with argument 'install'
//   storing the process in variable npmInstall
var npmInstall = spawn('npm', ['install'], {
  cwd: process.cwd(),
  stdio: 'inherit'
});

// listen for the 'exit' event
//   which fires when the process exits
npmInstall.on('exit', function(code, signal) {
  if (code === 0) {
    // process completed successfully
  } else {
    // handle error
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks sooo much! Here's what I was able to build with your help : ) https://gist.github.com/CostaMichailidis/11181252

Comment: This prints the output, but how will it pass the password?

Comment: Yeah, this doesn't clearly explain how the actual writing in response happens.  Also, what if I need to perform multiple rounds of prompt & response (i.e. request for username followed by request for password)?  Would it be a set of nested `execs`, or would that spawn a new process as well?